# Js/Node MongoDB - path to the nested object as a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could anyone tell me, how can I get the path of a nested object as a string, so that I can store it in a variable?

```
const testDoc = {
    name: "Test",
    readings : 500,
    metadata : {
        docs: {
            bills : ["un.txt", "deux.txt", "trois.txt"]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to save in MongoDB collection that the nested property bills that has a path = "testDoc.metadata.docs"

```
let pathToProperty = "testDoc.metadata.docs"
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need that path dynamically  when you're retrieving data from mongodb? If not, why not just put it there when you're inserting the doc into mongodb. But why do you need to keep the path there as a separate property if you know it already?

Comment: @h-sifat, thank you for your answer, you see I have a source collection from which I take fields that are being changed, and I put the record of that change into another (historyChange) collection. So if a field is nested,  I need to show that in the historyChange collection, what path it had.

Comment: So, to be clear you need to iterate a large document and get all it's props (even nested) path as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to get all paths(keys) of an object.

```js
const test = {
  a: "hi",
  b: {
    c: "there",
    d: "how",
    e: {
      f: "are",
      g: {
        h: "you",
        i: ["doing?", "Well, "],
        j: {
          k: "Alhamdulillah, I'm doing fine :)",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const allKeys = [];
const rootObjectName = "test";

function getAllPaths(object, allKeys, rootObjectKey = "") {
  for (let key of Object.keys(object)) {
    const currentKey = `${rootObjectKey}.${key}`;
    const currentValue = object[key];
    allKeys.push(currentKey);

    if (typeof currentValue === "object" && !Array.isArray(currentValue))
      getAllPaths(currentValue, allKeys, currentKey);
  }
}

getAllPaths(test, allKeys, rootObjectName);
console.log(allKeys);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @h-sifat, sorry mate, I thought no one is going to answer anymore, I found a solution in a library called => recursive-diff. It compares changes and gives a path if there was a changed nested object. So actually I didn't need all keys, but those that were chaged. I really like your solution

Comment: @КорвинКори, it's my pleasure. I guess now I'll make my own recursive-diff library and publish it on npm :').